# Connections to activate.adobe.com shown in process hacker

Tags: networking

I opened up the connections tab in Process Hacker and saw this...

[image: WTF?]

So my questions is this, What gives?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you made activate.adobe.com point to localhost in your hosts file so that you could steal whatever Adobe products you use it made process hacker show that as your address. In other words those are just programs connecting to the localhost and because you named localhost "activate.adobe.com" it is showing that as your local address.

Comment: +1 Also quite amusing that when modifying a hosts file people will just blindly follow instructions without knowing what they're doing.

Comment: @jb48394, @Joe Taylor Yeah I copied a friends huge ad-blocking hosts file (false accusation >_>), Anyway this leaves a couple of questions, how come all these programs are requesting from 127.0.0.1, and how come it does not say 127.0.0.1 (Is the reverse lookup the work of process hacker) and why doesn't it show localhost? (which appears higher up on the file).

Comment: That's how a lot of programs work by connecting back into themselves and other thing running on the computer... I am assuming it does not show "localhost" because it is not a FQDN like "activate.adobe.com". I would suggest flushing your hosts file if your friend was letting cracks alter it there might be malicious entries. Instead you should use Ad-Block for your browser assuming you are using Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @Neddy That's interesting point. Many programs use localhost to communicate with themselves, but to me this output looks a bit excessive.

Comment: @AndrejaKo He/She sorted by "Local Address" that is why they are clustered together like that.

Comment: @jb48394 I have been using adblock for years with loads of extra filter lists, (I _almost_ mentioned it before). Yeah you might be thinking why have both, well better safe then sorry right =p but seriously though I cleaned out all the entries I'm not using and now all is good ;)

Comment: @Neddy If you want extra security install NoScript and disable the Notifications then allow scripts on sites you know are secure or better yet get a copy of Sandboxie and install your browser in a sandbox and use NoScript along with Ad-Block.

Comment: Make sure you disable the notifications they can get retarded annoying and it takes some getting use to because every site using scripting so you have to allow on a per site basis when something is broken but 95% of the exploits coming at you through the browser use it. If you cant get use to it definitely try sandboxie.

Comment: Oh I like this one ;)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have activate.adobe.com set to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file. You or someone else may have done this to prevent adobe software from trying to activate. This program is then doing a reverse lookup for 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 and finding it in your hosts file.