# wired TCP/IP communication under system idle process

Tags: windows-10, virus, trojan, eset

I used Process explorer to view system idle process details. Under the TCP/IP tab i found a wired communication

its like this:

[image: system idle process wired TCP/IP]

I have updated paid license of ESET Smart Security 9 and it shows nothing important. but when i go to the remote address (3dns-2.adobe.com) ESET will block me.

Here is the output:

[image: html/refresh.bc trojan eset]

Is there any thing important to pay attention ?

What do you suggest me to do ?

Comment: Based on your recently posted questions, you seem to not understand what the System Idle Process is. I suggest reading more about it's purpose before delving into these deeper questions.

Comment: Your right. I forgot everything about checking for new processes to run. but its a different question , and yes its deeper. thanks for replay @root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a false positive, according to http://support.eset.com/alert5879/?viewlocale=en_US, you should update to **virus signature database version 13103 or later.** OR **submit false positive report to ESET lab**.

> If the detections are triggered after update to 13103 or higher, they
> should be correct. If you are unsure if a particular detection is ok
> or not, report it to the ESET Malware Research Lab:

[How do I submit a virus, website or potential false positive sample to the ESET lab?](http://support.eset.com/kb141/)

**[Regarding TCP connection on Process Explorer]**

There's no official documentation about this topic, refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232401/windows-pid-0-valid).

But if you test with `netstat -a -n -o` (refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802847/tcp-connection-owned-by-pid-zero)) in command prompt, you will notice the connection in **TIME_WAIT** state owned by **PID 0**. This ip should be listed under TCP/IP tab for System Idle Process on Process Explorer too.

Definition of TIME_WAIT in [rfc793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793):

> ```
> TIME-WAIT - represents waiting for enough time to pass to be sure
> the remote TCP received the acknowledgment of its connection
> termination request.
> ```

**PID 0** is not really a process, according to official [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f7309459-2711-4b2b-bcad-4b9d7739bbc7/special-pids?forum=netfxbcl) from msdn moderator:

> Yes, idle has PID 0 and system has PID 4 but they aren't really
> processes. The other processes have random PIDs.

To answer your question:

1. It's **normal behavior** if you found **TCP connection in TIME_WAIT
   state** under **System Idle Process**.
2. I'm not use ESET and i have no idea how it detected the suspicious connection, but IMHO you should double check your DNS settings and check with command `nslookup 3dns-2.adobe.com` to ensure it doesn't return a valid ip. If it does return a ip,  then you should do further research to ensure it's not a malicious ip. **[UPDATE]** Also see [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/260795/connections-to-activate-adobe-com-shown-in-process-hacker).

Comment: I'm on 13604. thanks for report part. but if i am right system idle should not have a tcp communication

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah No, it's normal "TIME_WAIT" own by system idle process which has PID 0, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802847/tcp-connection-owned-by-pid-zero

Comment: Please add the following details about time wait thing to your answer so I can mark you. Thanks

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah Edited.